# ASP.NET 5 DNX: How to shutdown application properly?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ibm-cloud, dnx, .net-core

When using a DNX(core) ASP.NET 5 application, the Configure() method can be used to subscribe to the following cancellation events:

```
IApplicationLifetime::ApplicationStarted
IApplicationLifetime::ApplicationStopping
IApplicationLifetime::ApplicationStopped
```

However, the only way I can see ATM to properly terminate an application is to call

```
IApplicationLifetime::StopApplication()
```

from within the application or press CTRL+C using Kestrel and running in a console.

Obviously the target here is to host the application as a background application (ideally as a cloud deployment).

Unfortunately I haven't been able to get a demo application to run on IIS.
When using IBM BlueMix, I've noticed that the stopping and stopped events are never fired and apparently the application is just stopped.

What is the proper way to deal with this? Are these events unreliable or am I doing something wrong?

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does IBM BlueMix ends a process? Does it kill it?

Comment: added some more info in my answer if that interest you. Basically, ASP.NET is using libuv and they might be limited in what they are doing unless they fork libuv (haven't checked if it isn't already done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, it's not possible to detect when the process is being killed.

There's 2 ways that even is going to fire as of now.

1. CTRL-C in the console window of Kestrel
2. The `Application` is being disposed.

[As far as it seems](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/20), they will have something ready when they hit RTM.

As for when a process gets killed, if BlueMix is closing on windows, it should send the proper `WM_Close` (0x0010) event and `SIGTERM` if you are under a Linux/OSX system.

If BlueMix is sending `SIGKILL`, then there's nothing that can be done about events.

**LIBUV Update:**

After digging a bit deeper, if you have any control over the signals that are sent, I recommend not sending any of those: `SIGILL`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGSEGV`, `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL`.

ASP.NET 5 is based on libuv and they might be limited to `SIGINT` or `SIGHUP` to terminate the application since libuv will not allow you to handle `SIGTERM`.

Comment: Cloud Foundy, which Bluemix is based on, is running the app on Linux and sending a SIGTERM followed by a SIGKILL if the app doesn't stop in 10 seconds.